# Datepicker field in react/redux form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, antd

Has anyone implemented a Timepicker/Datepicker with antd - I am having a difficult time implementing this into my react/redux form:

I've added my redux form in complete form,  to be clear I am not able to post selected value 3 fields - Datepicker, Timepicker, examType

```
   import React, { Component, PropTypes  } from 'react';
   import { reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'; 
   import { createPost } from '../actions/index';
   import { Link } from 'react-router'; 
   import { Select, Button,DatePicker, TimePicker } from 'antd';
   import moment from 'moment';


class PostsNew extends Component {
   static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        examTime:null,
        examDate:null
    }
    this.handleExamTypeChange = this.handleExamTypeChange.bind(this);
}

onSubmit(props) {
    // debugger
    this.props.createPost(props)
        .then(() => {
            // exams post has been created, navigate the user to the index
            // we navigate by calling this.context.router.push
            this.context.router.push('/profile/');
        });
   }

 handleUpdateDate(newValMoment, newValString) {
    this.setState({
    examDate: newValMoment
   });
 }

    handleUpdateTime(newValMoment, newValString) {
  console.log("Just called handle update time with new value " + 
   newValString);
  this.setState({
  examTime: newValString
  });
 }

  handleExamTypeChange(event) {
   console.log("New updated exam type is " + event.target.value);
    this.setState({examType : event.target.value});
 }


render() {
    const { fields: {firstname, 
                    lastName,
                    clientDOB,
                    clientPhone,
                    examStreetAddress,
                    examCity,
                    examState,
                    examZipCode,
                    policyAmount,
                    examDate,
                    examTime,
                    examType }, handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <h3>SCHEDULE AN EXAM</h3>
          <hr/> 
          <br/>

            <div className="text-xs-right">
                <Link to="/profile/">BACK</Link>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div className={`'form-group ${firstname.touched && 
   firstname.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                    <label>FIRSTNAME</label> 
                    <input type="text" placeholder="firstname" 
  className="form-control" {...firstname} />
                    <div className='text-help'>
                        {firstname.touched ? firstname.error: ''}
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 

            <div className={`'form-group ${lastName.touched && 
  lastName.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                <label>LASTNAME</label> 
                <input type="text" placeholder="lastname" className="form-
    control" {...lastName} />
                <div className='text-help'>
                    {lastName.touched ? lastName.error: ''}
                </div> 
            </div> 

            <div className={`'form-group ${clientDOB.touched && 
         clientDOB.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                <label>DATE OF BIRTH</label> 
                <input type="DATE" placeholder="DOB" format="YYYY-MM-DD" 
    className="col-lg-6 form-control" {...clientDOB} />
                <div className='text-help'>
                {clientDOB.touched ? clientDOB.error: ''}
                </div> 
            </div> 

            <div className={`'form-group ${clientPhone.touched && 
        clientPhone.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                <label>PHONE NUMBER</label> 
                <input type="TEXT" placeholder="ex. 8478675309" 
    className="col-lg-6 form-control" {...clientPhone} />
                <div className='text-help'>
                {clientPhone.touched ? clientPhone.error: ''}
                </div> 
            </div> 

            <div className={`'form-group ${examStreetAddress.touched && 
     examStreetAddress.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                <label>STREET ADDRESS</label> 
                <input type="ADDRESS" placeholder="street address" 
        className="form-control" {...examStreetAddress} />
                <div className='text-help'>
                {examStreetAddress.touched ? examStreetAddress.error: ''}
                </div> 
            </div> 

            <div className={`'form-group ${examCity.touched && 
         examCity.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                <label>CITY</label> 
                <input type="CITY" placeholder="city" className="form-control 
      col-md-4" {...examCity} />
                <div className='text-help'>
                {examCity.touched ? examCity.error: ''}
                </div> 
            </div> 

            <div className={`form-group ${examState.touched && 
     examState.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                <label>STATE</label> 
                <input type="text" placeholder="state" className="form-control 
    col-md-4" {...examState} />
                <div className='text-help'>
                {examState.touched ? examState.error: ''}
                </div> 
            </div> 

            <div className={`'form-group ${examZipCode.touched && 
      examZipCode.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                <label>ZIP</label> 
                <input type="number" placeholder="zip" className="col-lg-6 
      form-control" {...examZipCode} />
                <div className='text-help'>
                {examZipCode.touched ? examZipCode.error: ''}
                </div> 
            </div> 

            <div className={`'form-group ${policyAmount.touched && 
       policyAmount.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                <label>POLICY AMOUNT</label> 
                <input type="number" placeholder="policy amount" 
       className="col-lg-6 form-control" {...policyAmount} />
                <div className='text-help'>
                {policyAmount.touched ? policyAmount.error: ''}
                </div> 
            </div> 

            <div className='form-group col-sm-4'>
                <label>EXAM DATE</label> <br/>
                <DatePicker
                     {...examDate}
                     value={this.state.examDate}
                    onChange={(newValMoment, newValString) =>
                        this.handleUpdateDate(newValMoment, newValString)}
                    />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group col-sm-4 '>
                <label>EXAM TIME</label> <br/>               
                <TimePicker 
                    placeholder='SELECT'
                    format='hh:mm a'
                    {...examTime}
                    currentValue={this.state.examTime}
                    onChange={(newValMoment, newValString) =>
                        this.handleUpdateTime(newValMoment, newValString)}
                        />
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-4">
                <div className={`'form-group ${examType.touched && 
       examType.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
                    <label>EXAM TYPE</label> <br/>
                    <select style={{ width: 120 }} onChange=
       {this.handleExamTypeChange} {...examType}>
                        <option className="form-control" 
       value="">SELECT</option>
                        <option className="form-control" 
        value="PBU">PBU</option>
                        <option className="form-control" value="PBUEKG">PBU + 
       EKG</option>
                        {/*<div className='text-help'>
                        </div> */}
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-xs-12" >
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-
  primary">SUBMIT</button> 
                <Link to="/profile/" className="btn btn-danger">CANCEL</Link>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
            </div> 
        </form> 
       );
   }
  }


function validate(values) {
    const errors = {};

if (!values.firstname) {
    errors.firstname = 'client firstname';
}
if (!values.lastName) {
    errors.lastName = 'client lastname';
}
if (!values.clientDOB) {
    errors.clientDOB = 'client date of birth';
}
if (!values.examStreetAddress) {
    errors.examStreetAddress = 'street address of exam';
}
if (!values.examState) {
errors.examState = 'state of exam';
}
if (!values.examCity) {
errors.examCity = 'city of exam';
}
if (!values.examZipCode) {
errors.examZipCode = 'zipcode of exam';
}
if (!values.policyAmount) {
errors.policyAmount = 'policy amount';
}
return errors;
}

  //connect first argument is mapStatetoProps, 2nd is mapDipatchToProps
 // reduxForm: 1st is form config, 2nd is mapDipatchToProps, 3rd is 
mapDispatchToProps

export default reduxForm({
form: "PostsNewForm",
fields: ['firstname',
        'lastName',
        'examType',
        'examStreetAddress',
        'examCity',
        'examState',
        'examZipCode',
        'policyAmount',
        'clientDOB',
        'clientPhone',
        'examDate',
        'examTime',
        'examType'],
     validate
}, null,{ createPost } ) (PostsNew);
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I am not getting an error, but when I submit my redux form to an api end, which creates a record in a MySQL database, the field examTime is "undefined", the selected value does not attach itself to the examTime.

Comment: did you get value in newValString?

Comment: put your full code here...

Comment: I've updated my question to show the full redux form - I am having trouble with 3 fields being saved to my database - datepicker, timepicker, and examType